# jQuery resize() event is not working while draggable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I am trying to use jQuery to make "Draggable" into the DIV(id=sortable), but it's not working "Resize".

1. Draggable "Drag me down" DIV into DIV(id=sortable)
2. Draggable is working fine within the DIV(id=sortable)

> 3. Resizable is not working within the DIV(id=sortable)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**Script** and **HTML**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable").sortable({
    revert: true
  });
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

  $('.resizemove').resizable();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div id="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight ui-state-default resizemove DivStyle" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:block; background: lightyellow;">Drag me down</div><br>
</div>

<div id="sortable" class="main-wrap" style="border:5px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);padding: 5px; clear: both;">
  <div class="ui-state-default resizemove DivStyle" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:block; background: lightbluered;">One</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default resizemove DivStyle" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:block; background: lightpink;">Two</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default resizemove DivStyle" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:block; background: lightgray;">Three</div>
  <div class="ui-state-default resizemove DivStyle" style="width:100px; height:100px; display:block; background: lightseagreen;">Four</div>
  <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ramalingam07/84cvchas/)

Comment: I do not think you can resize something while you are dragging an item. After it has been dragged, and added to soemthing else, I suspect you will need to `refresh` it.

Comment: Also, from the fiddle, you may want to consider using a `handle` for your draggable. It looks like since both resizeable and draggable use `click` event, draggable seems to win out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would adjust your Draggable Handle. For example:

```
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: "#sortable",
    handle: $(this).not(".ui-resizable-handle"),
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/84cvchas/2/