# How to make draggable div resizable using jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have created few widgets, which should be `draggable` anywhere on the screen and `resizable` by the user. I managed to make them `draggable`, but can't make them `resizable`. here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/vaxobasilidze/reL880g8/

What am I doing wrong? I have other elements too, which I make draggable and resizable by the same way, but for an unknown reason this does not work only on this widget.

```js
function foo(){
  $('.channel').each(function() {
    $(this).draggable({
      containment: $('.screens'),
      stack: '.channel',
      drop: function (event, ui) {
      
      },
      drag: function(){
        var draggedItemId = $(this).attr('id');
      },
      stop: function(){
        var draggedItemId = $(this).attr('id');
      }
    }).resizable();
  });
}

function makeDraggable(){
  var height = $('.channels').height();
  $('.ram').draggable({
    stack: '.ram',
  }).resizable();
}

makeDraggable();
foo();
```

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2c2c2c;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #2c2c2c), color-stop(37%, #3d3d3d), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(100%, #131313));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c2c2c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #b8c0c8;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.ram {
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 140px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  resize: none;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.ram:hover {
  resize: both;
}

#ramUsageContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#ramUsageContainer svg {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px #647384 );
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px #647384 );
}

.usageHeader {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
}

.usagePercent {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ElementQueries.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/2.1.8/jsPlumb.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="channel elementTable widget ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle Usage ram widgetDropped ui-resizable" name="RAM" id="2" style="left: 564px; top: 284px; z-index: 1003;" oncontextmenu="return false;">                                 
      <div id="ramUsageContainer">
        <p class="usageHeader">RAM Usage</p>
        <p class="usagePercent">65.7%</p>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
          <path d="M 50,50 m -47,0 a 47,47 0 1 1 94,0" stroke="#353740" stroke-width="6" fill-opacity="0"></path>
          <path d="M 50,50 m -47,0 a 47,47 0 1 1 94,0" stroke="rgb(167,87,0)" stroke-width="6" fill-opacity="0" style="stroke-dasharray: 147.708, 147.708; stroke-dashoffset: 50.6639;"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery resize() event is not working while draggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48557144/jquery-resize-event-is-not-working-while-draggable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function foo(){
  $('.channel').each(function() {
    $(this).resizable().draggable({
      containment: $('.screens'),
      stack: '.channel',
      drop: function (event, ui) {
      
      },
      drag: function(){
        var draggedItemId = $(this).attr('id');
      },
      stop: function(){
        var draggedItemId = $(this).attr('id');
      }
    });
  });
}

function makeDraggable(){
  var height = $('.channels').height();
  $('.ram').resizable().draggable({
    stack: '.ram',
  });
}

makeDraggable();
foo();
```

```css
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #2c2c2c;
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%, #2c2c2c), color-stop(37%, #3d3d3d), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(66%, #353535), color-stop(100%, #131313));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #2c2c2c 0%, #3d3d3d 37%, #353535 66%, #353535 66%, #131313 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2c2c2c', endColorstr='#131313', GradientType=1);
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #b8c0c8;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.ram {
  width: 250px;
  height: 140px;
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 140px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  resize: none;
  padding: 7px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.ram:hover {
  resize: both;
}

#ramUsageContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#ramUsageContainer svg {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px #647384 );
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 3px #647384 );
}

.usageHeader {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
}

.usagePercent {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ResizeSensor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/css-element-queries/0.4.0/ElementQueries.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/2.1.8/jsPlumb.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css"/>

<body>
    <div class="channel elementTable widget ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle Usage ram widgetDropped ui-resizable" name="RAM" id="2" style="left: 564px; top: 284px; z-index: 1003;" oncontextmenu="return false;">
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e"></div>
      <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s"></div>                                 
      <div id="ramUsageContainer">
        <p class="usageHeader">RAM Usage</p>
        <p class="usagePercent">65.7%</p>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
          <path d="M 50,50 m -47,0 a 47,47 0 1 1 94,0" stroke="#353740" stroke-width="6" fill-opacity="0"></path>
          <path d="M 50,50 m -47,0 a 47,47 0 1 1 94,0" stroke="rgb(167,87,0)" stroke-width="6" fill-opacity="0" style="stroke-dasharray: 147.708, 147.708; stroke-dashoffset: 50.6639;"></path>
        </svg>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

One more update is add `resizable` first then call `draggable` like `$(this).resizable().draggable()`  I did such changes into the code. you can use the same code now.

Comment: See my edit working in chrome as well, just changed the css version. you are on the way now, its working perfectly.

Comment: Hope you found code useful. I updated code snippet instead of fiddle. It works in all browsers

Comment: This is also a correct answer, so I'll accept it instead of mine. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by using java-script here is working demo  and in Css The only important style is position: absolute, the rest is up to you:

```js
dragElement(document.getElementById(("mydiv")));

function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
  if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header")) {
    /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
    document.getElementById(elmnt.id + "header").onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  } else {
    /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
  }

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
    // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
    document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;
    // set the element's new position:
    elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
    elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
  }

  function closeDragElement() {
    /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
    document.onmouseup = null;
    document.onmousemove = null;
  }
}
```

```css
#mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
      width: 300px;
resize: both;
overflow: auto;
}

#mydivheader {
    padding: 10px;
    cursor: move;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: #2196F3;
    color: #fff;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Draggable DIV Element</h1>

<p>Click and hold the mouse button down while moving the DIV element</p>

<div id="mydiv">
  <div id="mydivheader">Click here to move</div>
  <p>Move</p>
  <p>this</p>
  <p>DIV</p>
</div>
```

reference from:- https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_draggable

Answer (score 1):

I have found a problem in my code. Code was correct, simply because of unknown reasons, after loading saved diagram application was creating new resize sensors on widgets borders. So I had few resize sensors placed on top of each other, but only one of them was working, which I could not click on. The perfect solution for me was to simply delete old resize sensors with this code:

```
$('.channel .resize-sensor').remove();
$('.channel .ui-resizable-handle').remove();
```

After that, I simply call another function that makes them draggable and resizable:

```
makeDraggable();
```